# Nested Group by based on string value Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, group-by, filtering

Let us say I have a string array with values like -

```
animal
animal.mammal
animal.bird
animal.reptile
animal.mammal.human
animal.mammal.horse
animal.bird.crow
animal.reptile.snake
```

When I have to display this array, I want to display it like this -

```
-animal
  -animal.mammal
    -animal.mammal.human
    -animal.mammal.horse
  -animal.bird
    -animal.bird.crow
  -animal.reptile
    -animal.reptile.snake
```

What should be my approach? I should use group by or filter or what?
I am using angular 6 and material UI.

Comment: You will have to group, but not sure if angular provides any in-built one. You can create a custom one though

Comment: Can you shed some more light please?

Comment: Loop with `ngfor` to display on html, https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: Post your input JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a begin of what you need :

```
const groups = arr => {
    const res = [];
    arr.forEach(v => {
        let current = res
        const splits = v.split('.');
        splits.forEach(s => {
            if (current[s] === undefined) {
                current[s] = [];
            }
            current = current[s];
        });
        current.push(v);
    }
    return res;

 groups(yourArrayHere);
```

input :

```
const arr = ['animal', 'animal.mammal', 'animal.mammal.human'];
```

output :

```
[
   'animal': [
       0: 'animal',
       'animal.mammal': [
           0: 'animal.mammal.human'
       ]
   ]
]
```

**Edit :**

You can also use reduce statement wich works pretty well too :)

```
const groups = arr => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
       let current = acc
        v.split('.').forEach(s => {
            if (current[s] === undefined) {
                current[s] = [];
            }
            current = current[s];
        });
        current.push(v);
        return acc;
    }, []);
};

groups(theArray);
```